# vdpau on Ubuntu 13.10 and mesa 9.2.1

Tags: ati, 13.10, mesa, vdpau

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10. I have a Radeon HD 4570 card and I want to use the hardware acceleration capabilities that were introduced with linux 3.10 in the mesa 9.2

So my question is: since I have a linux 3.11 and mesa 9.2, do I really need to compile the mesa library with --enable-vdpau option enabled? I have installed the libvdpau from the repository but no acceleration. Should I compile and then install the latest mesa(I don't want to mess my newly installed Ubuntu 3.10)?

Thanks!

Comment: Ohh..for all the devils, I've just compiled and installed mesa 10. Now vdpau is working, but guess what: glxinfo reports my gl version to 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu does not ship XVMC and VDPAU drivers Mesa required for Radeon VDPAU by default. However, you can get VDPAU for Radeon working easily, ***simply by installing only the libg3dvl-mesa package for your architecture from Oibaf PPA***. You **don't** even have to upgrade to the latest Mesa from the PPA or recompile it. Here are the download links

*Recently the graphics drivers from Oibaf PPA work brilliant, however I still prefer stock packaged Ubuntu drivers for stability and for keeping my system minimalistic*

After you revert from Mesa 10 to stock 9.2.1 Mesa, you can simply do the following :

1) Download and install the deb depending on your architecture

- [32 bit](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12U4rSoiDIXTkQyMUtCNUpjZDQ/edit?usp=sharing)
- [64 bit](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12U4rSoiDIXMjZEalRsd0JBNlU/edit?usp=sharing)

2) `sudo apt-get install libvdpau1 vdpauinfo`

3) Reboot.